# How to access security group of classic load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have created a classic load balancer and auto scaling policy which launch 2 instance successfully; now when I logged in through ssh to one of  the load balancer.

`ssh -i "mykeypair.pem" ec2-user@my-load-balancer-1222.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

we looged in with the teminla

*[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-86 ~ ]* << here this Ip is one of the instance which was created by auto scaling

now I want to check the security-group of the elb from `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/security-groups`  command  but it display the instnace security group name not the elb security group.

My question is  how can we check the elb security group?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have SSH'ed into one of the 2 instances behind the load balancer (I doubt you can SSH into the ELB itself), so that's why you're seeing the security group of that instance.

I believe the way to check the ELB's security group is by using the AWS CLI (or one of their SDKs), using the

`aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name my-load-balancer`

You can find more details in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-load-balancers.html)

Note: of course, if you wanted to run this command from within the EC2 instance you SSH'ed into, you would need to make sure you have access to make that invocation. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) for more info, on getting set up.

Comment: yes , I can check via cli ; but my concern is when we logged in via ELB DNS than can we logged into the other instance from the elb logged in terminal? means using ssh or any other way?

Comment: hmmm... I'm not sure using the ELB for SSH access, is what you want. That way you don't know which of the EC2 instances you're connecting to. It might be best to connect using the EC2 instance's public IP.

Comment: Ahh...We can not connect with ec2 instance's public IP as we set inbound rule on _ec2-instance security group_ to allow ssh only via _ELB- security group_ only

Comment: I think that might be something you should reconsider. Sounds like a [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host) might be closer to what you need -- obviously don't know your overall setup though and it's probably also beyond the scope of this question. Would you mind marking answer as accepted, if it solved the original issue you posted?

Answer (score 1):

You should not SSH into an instance via a Load Balancer.

An SSH session is persistent -- you wish to continue talking to the same server. This clashes with the concept of a Load Balancer, which distributes traffic across multiple servers.